# History of Fargues-Fontaine curve

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, p-adic

In this [paper](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~pierre.colmez/preface-FF.pdf), Pierre Colmez wrote about some history of the Fargue-Fontaine curve. In this [schedule of London Number Theory Study Group](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/LNTS/Fargues_conjecture_study_group.pdf), Fargues was said to give a talk on November 15th on " Where does the curve and the conjecture come from? What happened in Trieste, Orsay and Berkeley? ". " What happened in Trieste " is well-documented by Colmez. Is there any reference about "what happened in Orsay and Berkeley"?

Comment: Berkeley course notes: http://math.bu.edu/people/jsweinst/Math274/ScholzeLectures.pdf

Comment: @nfdc, that's a link to 100 pages of notes. Can you narrow it down a bit?

Comment: @nfdc23, the Berkeley notes is the origin of my query. In the polished version (http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Berkeley.pdf), Scholze & Weinstein mentioned that Fargues formulated the conjecture during the semester, but they kept the original perspective of the notes without highlighting the conjecture.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: All I meant was that one thing relevant which happened in Berkeley was that the course introduced the theory of diamonds (which provides a context for some of Fargues' ideas).

Answer (score 1):

The notes for the talk are indeed available in Fargues' website:

https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~laurent.fargues/Expos%C3%A9%20Imperial%20.pdf